# "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64" In SDL 2 (macOS)

Tags: c++, c, macos, sdl-2

Basically, I was trying to make my first SDL2 game in C but encountered the same error every time. `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64` Where i can't call simple functions like the `SDL_CreateWindow` from SDL. I thought something like this would happen because I have a very limited understanding of C and C++ as I only just learnt the language and concepts.

Originally, I downloaded the SDL 2 source code (SDL2.framework and put it into) the `/Library/Frameworks` file. Then I simply tried to include SDL2 by using the path `#include </Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers/SDL.h>` to absolutely no avail.

- I have tried looking up solutions but they all seem to be tutorials of EXACTLY what I have done or just answers for Windows users (I could rant about this).
- I followed tutorials on the SDL website but I didn't understand them very well (I am new to shell and only 13) and most of the commands didn't work.
- I tried troubleshooting the problem myself by looking inside of the SDL2 files and found these functions.

Please help, I have been searching for a while. Ideally I would just want a clear explanation (for newbies) on how to setup SDL2 so that I can compile my program with SDL2. This is what I tested:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "/Users/christianlincoln/Documents/programs/c/SDL2.framework/Versions/A/Headers/SDL.h"
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    SDL_Window *window;
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    window = SDL_CreateWindow(
        "Game",                  // window title
        0,                         // initial x position
        0,                         // initial y position
        640,                               // width, in pixels
        480,                               // height, in pixels
        SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL                  // flags - see below
    );
    printf("Hello!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Sorry for wording my question wrong or being outright incompetent.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to link to the sdl libraries. You can't just include the headers.

Comment: how do i do this?

Comment: I am not an expert with the macos. I expect if you downloaded the source, that you did not configure it with CMake to generate a project file for xcode and build it to create the libraries compatible with your compiler. And then go into your compiler settings for your project to add the location of the library to link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out, the problem was I also needed to compile the source libraries but I had no idea how to do this and how to ensure that gcc would link everything together.
All the other tutorials were just telling me to put the framework in /Library/Frameworks which was wrong.

Turns out I had to mess around with gcc for a while after compiling:

```
gcc game.c -I/usr/local/include/SDL2 -lSDL2
```

Although I am still unsure of how to do this with things like OpenGL.